# Not a Craft CMS designer and need help

Tags: link, menu

I am actually doing on page SEO for a Craft site. I created 4 new pages. I have no idea how to publish them, put the links into a block on the home page, add an image to the content, and add to the menu via a dropdown. Is this all possible?

I am well versed in WP but not Craft.

Comment: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/ or hire someone who does know.

Comment: The thing is: Craft is really flexible thus there are 1000 ways to achieve certain things. We don't know how your menu is created and what former developers did unless you show us your code

Comment: I would definitely entertain hiring someone to make the few edits I need

Answer (score 4):

Craft often requires a different approach than Wordpress, but can be just as easy and powerful to use when set up correctly. The big unknown in your situation is how your content architecture and templates are set up.

Content architecture and template decisions in Craft are custom from site to site and designed by the firm that created or maintains the website. To help further with you question, we'd need to understand how your sections and navigation are set up, if your sections have URLs, what assumptions your templates are designed to make about the content they output, and so on. Getting training from the firm who built the site or hiring a consultant to walk you through your site and give you a tour of how things work could be helpful in your situation.

A few resources that could help you get started:

- [Craft Feature Videos](https://craftcms.com/features/matrix) - Short videos on how key features in Craft work
- [Straight Up Craft Training](https://straightupcraft.com/training) - Free, weekly intro training
- [Mijingo Video Course](https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/craft-cms-3-tutorials/) - Overview of building a site in Craft

If you are in the situation where you are looking for a consultant or firm to work with, there are a couple of Craft professional listings and job directories. At the time of this post:

- [Straight Up Craft - Jobs](https://straightupcraft.com/jobs)
- [Straight Up Craft - Professionals](https://straightupcraft.com/professionals)
- [Work With Craft](https://www.workwithcraft.com/jobs)
- [Work With Craft - Professionals](https://www.workwithcraft.com/professionals)
- [Craft CMS Partners](https://craftcms.com/partners)
- [Craft Slack #jobs channel](https://craftcms.com/community)

Comment: I would definitely entertain hiring someone to make the few edits I need

Comment: @EAlexBungener this is a QA site so I've updated my answer above to point you toward some resources where you could find someone that could help you out.